# how to disable tooltip dynamcically in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I can disable the tooltip statically.
But I want to disable tooltip dynamically when i click flatbutton.But Couldnt disable dynamically and i have no idea to do that.
This is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main(){
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: HelloWorld(),debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,));
}
class HelloWorld extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HelloWorldState createState() => _HelloWorldState();
}

class _HelloWorldState extends State<HelloWorld> {

  bool check = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
              TopToolbar(),
              FlatButton(
                child: Text("Disable Tooltip"),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    TopToolbar toolbar = new TopToolbar();
                    toolbar.showTooltip = false;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ]),
          ),
        ));
  }
}

class TopToolbar extends StatefulWidget {

  bool showTooltip;
  final Color backgroundColor;
  final double height;
  bool isVisible;
  TopToolbar({
    this.height = 55,
    this.isVisible = true,
    this.backgroundColor = const Color(0xFFEEEEEE),
    Key key,this.showTooltip=true,
  }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _TopToolbarState createState() => _TopToolbarState();
}

class _TopToolbarState extends State<TopToolbar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (widget.isVisible) {
      return Container(
        foregroundDecoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border(
            bottom: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 1),
        color: widget.backgroundColor,
        height: widget.height,
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Positioned(
              top: 7,
              right: 60,
              height: 40,
              width: 40,
              child: RawMaterialButton(
                elevation: 0.0,
                fillColor: widget.backgroundColor,
                splashColor: Colors.grey[300],
                child: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.bookmark,
                    color: Colors.grey[500],
                    size: 25,
                  ),
                  onPressed: (){},
                  tooltip: widget.showTooltip ? "Bookmark" : null,
                ),
                onPressed: (){},
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return Container();
    }
  }
}
```

If I give statically false. it works fine.
For example : If add child like TopToolbar(showTooltip : false),it works fine,
But If i give toolbar.showTooltip = false in Flatbutton onPressed method,it doesnt work.
I want to disble it in dynamically. please help me to do that.

Comment: Please help me to solve this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

we can hide or deactivate tooltip programmatically like below,

```
Future.delayed(
  Duration(seconds: 2),
  () {
    tooltip?.deactivate();
  }
);
```

Here, we can set time according to your requirement.(Currently, we are set 2 sec.)

Answer (score 2):

There is a class for this, called TooltipVisibility (see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TooltipVisibility-class.html):

```
  TooltipVisibility(
      visible: false, // Here goes your visibility variable or whatever
      child: Tooltip(
         message: "Should I like tooltips?"
         child: ...
      )
   )
```

That should also make visible/invisible all the descendant tooltips in that Widget tree.

Answer (score 1):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: HelloWorld(),
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  ));
}

class HelloWorld extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HelloWorldState createState() => _HelloWorldState();
}

class _HelloWorldState extends State<HelloWorld> {
  bool check = false;
  bool showTooltip = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
      child: Center(
        child: Column(children: <Widget>[
          TopToolbar(showTooltip: showTooltip),
          FlatButton(
            child: Text("Disable Tooltip"),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                showTooltip = false;
              });
            },
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    ));
  }
}

class TopToolbar extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool showTooltip;
  final Color backgroundColor;
  final double height;
  final bool isVisible;
  TopToolbar({
    this.height = 55,
    this.isVisible = true,
    this.backgroundColor = const Color(0xFFEEEEEE),
    Key key,
    this.showTooltip = true,
  }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _TopToolbarState createState() => _TopToolbarState();
}

class _TopToolbarState extends State<TopToolbar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (widget.isVisible) {
      return Container(
        foregroundDecoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border(
            bottom: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 1),
        color: widget.backgroundColor,
        height: widget.height,
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Positioned(
              top: 7,
              right: 60,
              height: 40,
              width: 40,
              child: RawMaterialButton(
                elevation: 0.0,
                fillColor: widget.backgroundColor,
                splashColor: Colors.grey[300],
                child: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.bookmark,
                    color: Colors.grey[500],
                    size: 25,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {},
                  tooltip: widget.showTooltip ? 'Bookmark' : null,
                ),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return Container();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `tooltip` property is now removed from `RawMaterialButton`. Also null safety prevents assigning `null` to several properties.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this method to hide tooltips:

```
Tooltip(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0),
    ),
    textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0)),
    message: 'Certificates',
    child: Container()
);
```

Comment: This may still show an empty small tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

Make the property message=''  // empty string

```
setState((){messageText=''});

Tooltip(
  message: messageText,
  ...
)
```